# Selecting property from nested JSON array stored within Logic App variable

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am struggling to select a property from a JSON array that I've stored in a variable (as an array). I receive the following error:

> The execution of template action 'Select' failed: The evaluation of 'query' action >'where' expression '{
> "Response": "@variables('UserEvents').responseStatus.response",
> "trest": ""
> }' failed: 'The template language expression >'variables('UserEvents').responseStatus.response' cannot be evaluated because property >'responseStatus' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an > integer index. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

The JSON is below:

```
[
  {
    "value": [
      {
        "responseStatus": {
          "response": "notResponded",
          "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to select the 'response' property only by using the following expression:

@variables('UserEvents').responseStatus.response

I have tried adding [0] to various parts of the above expression but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I am sure it's pretty simple and I'm just getting the syntax wrong, but am completely stuck!

Any help appreciated - thanks.

Adrian

Answer (score 2):

```
 @{
    variables('UserEvents') ? ['value'] ? [0] ? ['response']
  }
```

Try that. The integer index mentioned in the error is the way around this. May need to play around with the structure to make it match your data but [0] will make it select the first object within your value array.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to get the properties inside a nested JSON

**WAY - 1** (Try to get properties using For-each loop)

For this we need to use 2 for-each loops to retrieve the property inside the nested JSON After Parsing the JSON. Below is the screenshot of my logic app for your reference.
[image]

**WAY - 2** (Using Dynamic Expression)
Here is the Expression that worked for me.

```
body('Parse_JSON')?[0]?['value']?[0]?['responseStatus']?['response']
```

Since it is in Array of Array format we need to mention the index of the array. Below is the screenshot of my logic app for your reference :

[image]

output :
[image]